# Passing data between two button in one activity?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have problem where the button cannot passing the int data 
here is the code
I want to make comparison between TotalKalori and bmr, but it seems TotalKalori cannot be solve in last section, it it saying TotalKalori cannot be resolved into variable, how do I solve this? Thank you

```
package lynn.calculate.KaunterKalori;

 import lynn.calculate.KaunterKalori.R;
 import android.app.Activity;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CalculateAll extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//private int TotalKalori;
protected int totalKalori1;
protected int totalKalori2;
protected int totalKalori3;

EditText EstimateCalorie;
TextView TotalKaloriSehari;
TextView totalsarapan;
TextView totallunch;
TextView totaldinner;
TextView calorieneeds;
TextView resultDiff;


public CalculateAll() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculate_all);

    View kiraButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonKiraAll);
    kiraButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    View bezaButton = findViewById(R.id.caloriediff);
    bezaButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    //

    TotalKaloriSehari = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JumlahKalori);
    totalsarapan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sarapantext);
    totallunch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lunchtext);
    totaldinner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dinnertext);
    EstimateCalorie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BMR);
    calorieneeds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMR);
    resultDiff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        totalKalori1 = extras.getInt("totalBreakfast");
        totalKalori2 = extras.getInt("totalLunch");
        totalKalori3 = extras.getInt("totalDinner");

    }

    totalsarapan.setText(totalKalori1 + "");
    totallunch.setText(totalKalori2 + "");
    totaldinner.setText(totalKalori3 + "");




}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonKiraAll) {


     int TotalKalori = calculateTotalKalori(totalKalori1, totalKalori2,
                totalKalori3);
        TotalKaloriSehari.setText(TotalKalori + "");



    }

    if (v.getId()== R.id.caloriediff) {

         int TotalKalori = calculateTotalKalori(totalKalori1, totalKalori2,
                    totalKalori3);

        int nilaikalori = Integer.parseInt(EstimateCalorie.getText()
                .toString());
        //TotalKalori = Integer.parseInt(TotalKaloriSehari.getText().toString());

        int bmr = calculatebmr(nilaikalori);


    //  String deskripsiKalori = describekalori(bmr);


    //  resultDiff.setText("kalori makanan" + TotalKalori + " calori diperlukan " + bmr + "=" + deskripsiKalori);
        resultDiff.setText("kalori makanan = " + TotalKalori + " calori diperlukan = " + bmr);
        }
    } 
        //Intent n = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(n);



        //







private String describekalori(int bmr) {

 if (bmr < TotalKalori ) {
        return "bykkan makan";
    } else if (bmr == TotalKalori) {

        return "kekalkan jumlah kalori ini";

    } else if (bmr > TotalKalori) {

        return "kurangkan pengambilan kalori";

    } else
        return "oiii";

}       




public int calculateTotalKalori(int totalKalori1, int totalKalori2,
        int totalKalori3) {
    return (int) (totalKalori1 + totalKalori2 + totalKalori3);

}

public int calculatebmr(int nilaikalori) {
    return (int) (nilaikalori);
}


}

// the comparison that I can't solve is the 
// the TotalKalori cannot resolved into variable? how do I solve this? thank you
private String describekalori(int bmr) {

 if (bmr < TotalKalori ) {
        return "bykkan makan";
    } else if (bmr == TotalKalori) {

        return "kekalkan jumlah kalori ini";

    } else if (bmr > TotalKalori) {

        return "kurangkan pengambilan kalori";

    } else
        return "oiii";

}
```

Comment: Add your data to the Intent as an Extra.

Comment: passing data between 2 button.

Comment: @Sparky i already,but the TotalKalori still didn't pass to the button2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pass **bmr** to **MainActivity** on **caloriediff** button press. Use the following code on button press to pass data:

```
    Intent n = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(“myValue“,""+bmr);
    n.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(n);
```

Now in your **MainActivity** retrieve your data from the bundle:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String retbmr = bundle.getString(“myValue”);
```

---

Then parse in to integer if you need:

```
int nbmr = Integer.parseInt(retbmr);
```

or directly as:

```
int nbmr = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString(“myValue”));
```

Comment: @chilora7 can you please explain what you really want, it is not clear enough IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, but I want pass data in one activity between two button, someone suggest me to use setTag() and getTag() method, but I still did get the correct way to solve this.

Comment: I want to pass data between two button here, the button1 is buttonKiraAll and button2 is caloriediff, the TotalKalori in button1 cannot be pass to button2.

Comment: Imran Rana, I already edit the question, I really hope you can help. thank you again.

Comment: If all you need is to pass a data from button1 to button2, then just make the variable global so that both button has access to it. Say, declare **TotalKalori** in the section where you declared `protected int totalKalori1; protected int totalKalori2; ...`. Then both button have a access to it, use this variable in both buttons, if **button1** modifies it, **buttton2** gets the modified data. I hope you understand @chilora7

Comment: imran rana, what you mean is I have to put  int TotalKalori = calculateTotalKalori(totalKalori1, totalKalori2,
                totalKalori3);
        TotalKaloriSehari.setText(TotalKalori + "");
in button2 also???

Comment: Imran Rana! thanks, I have pass the data but the second problem now is how I want to the comparison between the data?                   private String describekalori(int bmr) {
 
  if (bmr < TotalKalori ) {
        return "bykkan makan";
    } else if (bmr == TotalKalori) {

        return "kekalkan jumlah kalori ini";

    } else if (bmr > TotalKalori) {

        return "kurangkan pengambilan kalori";

    } else
        return "oiii";

}       the comparison of TotalKalori and bmr,(the insert data) Thank you very much, and really glad that you were helping me :))

Comment: @chilora7 you only want to use value of **TotalKalori of button1** in button2 right? Then declare **int TotalKalori** only once globally (in the section you declared `protected int totalKalori1; protected int totalKalori2; ...` and simply use it for both both buttons like: in button1 `TotalKalori = calculateTotalKalori(totalKalori1, totalKalori2,totalKalori3);` this value is global so button2 already can acess it by simply using `TotalKalori` where you need.

Comment: @chilora7 is your problem solved? I didn't saw your last comment(as I was typing then).

Comment: Imran Rana,the passing data between the two button solved, :)) then right now I have problem where I can't make the comparison between TotalKalori and bmr. I will edit the question and show you. I already declare TotalKalori into public int TotalKalori, but still I can't make the comparison between TotalKalori and bmr. Thank you Imran Rana :D

Comment: Enable `//private int TotalKalori;` by removing **//** replace  `int TotalKalori` of both button1 and 2 by  `TotalKalori` only and your problem should be solved, do it and inform me :)

Comment: I'm saying declare TotalKalori only once here `private int TotalKalori;` and don't redeclare it locally anywhere else as you are doing by writing `int TotalKalori = calculateTotalKalori(totalKalori1, totalKalori2,totalKalori3);` in buttons. remove **int** from these lines i mean use `TotalKalori = calculateTotalKalori(totalKalori1, totalKalori2,totalKalori3);` only and let me know

Comment: I have try the TotalKalori only method, but it seems I still cannot pass the value to the comparison, nway thank you :)

Comment: @chilora7 show me your final code you tried via editing or using pastebin

Comment: @chilora7 take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/0VdEMuQg), it works and not a different case from your's one. Just think **x** as your **TotalKalori**

Comment: What problem are you facing now, I mean explain your problem now: what should you get and what are you getting?

Comment: oh I want to make the comparison between TotalKalori and bmr, the things is, the TotalKalori cannot be read. it says that TotalKalori cannot be resolved into variable.

Comment: I have simulated your project with the single activity you provided by giving some random value to totalkalori1,2,3 & it works fine. I h uploaded the complete sample [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?ksj3r89762cr1e8). Give it a try and one thing: don't use same id **BMR** for both a TextView & a EditText. Let me know about your update.